# JCarousel not working in FF but working fine in IE

Tags: security, firefox, jcarousel

Thanks in advance for any help!

I am working on building a site on Business Catalyst and have used jCarousel in it. The test site is it4kids.businesscatalyst.com.

I cannot get the 3 jCarousel instances to work in FF, but all fine in IE. I have IE 9.0.81110.16421 and FF 10.0.1

I can see in Firebug that there is an error on SCRIPTS.JS file shown as:

> Blockquote

SECURITY ERROR

[Break On This Error]   if(sheets[sheetIndex].cssRules || sheets[sheetIndex].rules){
SRIPTS.JS line 717

> Blockquote

This error does not appear in IE (when using Firebug lite to view).

Any thoughts / ideas will be really appreciated. I am sure it is a small issue that I cannot seem to see from spending too much time on trying to find it!

Thanks again
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You're presumably loading some cross-site stylesheet and jCarousel apparently tries to examine loaded stylesheets.  Firefox doesn't allow that for cross-site stylesheets because it would be a security hole.

You need to either make sure all your stylesheets are same-origin or fix the relevant jCarousel code to either try/catch or not look at cross-site sheets at all.

Comment: Hi Boris, sorry for the late reply! I figured it out... I had two JS fuctions of the same name causing the conflict... Thanks!